# (UWP)Web view opening empty html file when trying to open using Navigator, Source file is in the app package on navigation for c#

Tags: c#, html, windows, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a scenario when I have to authenticate the app with a provider and then redirect back to the app on a successful login.

The redirect Url is `ms-appx-web:///UI/app.html`.

This `app.html` has contents and these contents were loading before authentication and redirect.

After Redirecting the `app.html` has 0 lines of code, hence showing empty screen in the Windows app

For example: Authenticating using Microsoft account in the Windows app using Web view and after authenticating having a redirect_url back to Windows app using `ms-appx-web:///UI/app.html`. App.html is loaded but without content(Hence empty page).

Comment: Hi, How did you redirect? Is the `redirect_url` written in the Url, redirected directly after the authorization is completed? If so, did you make UrlEncode on `redirect_url`?

Comment: It is redirect_url and its not encoded

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode redirect url in you whole link.

But for UWP applications, the more recommended way to authorize is to use the **Web authentication broker**, which is used exclusively for authorization.

You can intercept the redirect url and set the `Source` property of the `WebView` based on the result. This is a safer practice.

Here is the document about the [Web authentication broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker).

Best regards.

Comment: Will this open the login page for the provider which we are trying to authorize?

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent to a small `WenView`, but provides some methods and properties for confirmation of authorization status.